# How to print \$ in R? Error: '\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""@:#[b19]\$"

Tags: r, command-line

How to make this a string in R? "@:#[b19]$r,$a" I'm using this in the system() function as a command line argument. This string is to be passed to paste0 to specify the binary name and other flags needed for the execution.

Comment: Double up the slashes: "@:#[b19]\\$r,\\$a"

Comment: @MrFlick But there are two slashes then. Are you saying this is not going to affect the command line execution?

Comment: There aren't two slashes then. That's just how you escape a single slash in a string literal. See the duplicate for more info. With R version 4 and later you can use a string like `r"(@:#[b19]\$r,\$a)"`